# How to generate a 32 byte private key?

Tags: apex, encryption, crypto

I am facing an issue while using the crypto class of salesforce
Below is the code snippet:

```
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
System.debug('KeyBlobSize:-'+cryptoKey.size());
System.debug('Blob:-'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cryptoKey));
```

With different bit size, I get 16, 24, and 32 bytes key respectively. Now if I store this key as string after doing a **base64Encode** for all different algorithms

```
Blob newcryptoKey128 = Blob.valueOf('xGhMrqIixKvQ4S1bqv8CYw==');
Blob newcryptoKey192 = Blob.valueOf('kBsCore1SUxZ8sTxSU5FCGqUGLhJ8IGq');
Blob newcryptoKey256 = Blob.valueOf('Wc0gT/1xfFAjlRwip7l7MmEdjw7DzMXamEHLjyCOQQ0=');
```

Now if I check the size of these blob values it got increased.

```
system.debug('Size1:-'+newcryptoKey128.size());
system.debug('Size2:-'+newcryptoKey192.size());
system.debug('Size3:-'+newcryptoKey256.size());
```

For 128 bits size , it became 24 bytes
For 192 bits size , it became 32 bytes
For 256 bits size , it became 44 bytes

It means I am generating the key with 256 bits size but I cant use the same in the encrypt code:

```
Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Test data to encrypted');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', newcryptoKey256, data);
```

Because it throws an error

> Exception: System.InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid private key. Must be 32 bytes.
>   StackTrace: Class.System.Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV: line 55, column 1

Reason: for 256 bits the size got increased to 44 bytes. Is it because of `EncodingUtil.base64Encode` or `Blob.valueOf`? What's the solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Above error is thrown because the private key is not 32 bytes. The expected and actual private key byte calculation is mismatching.

**Recommended approach to resolve this**

```
String algorithmName = 'AES256';
    Blob privateKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);        
    Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Test data to encrypted');
    Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV(algorithmName, privateKey, data);
    // In order to get the text out of a blob 
    String encodedString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
```

While decoding use EncodingUtil.base64Encode to convert it from string to blob and then decrypt the same.

```
Blob decodedData=EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encodedString);
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV(algorithmName, privateKey, decodedData);
```

Additionally, If you want to you want to specify your own initialization vector then use this method **encrypt(algorithmName, privateKey, initializationVector, clearText)** for encryption. Refer [Crypto class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) for same.

**Specifically, regarding above issues find below observations**

```
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
System.debug('KeyBlobSize:-'+cryptoKey.size());    
System.debug('Blob:-'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cryptoKey));
String Str =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cryptoKey);
Blob newcryptoKey128 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(Str);
system.debug('Size1:-'+newcryptoKey128.size());
Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Test data to encrypted');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', newcryptoKey128, data);
```

Above snippet will give the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, The issue is with 
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cryptoKey), when we do that encoding.util it increases the byte size. Thats the reason I am getting 24,32,44 bytes for 128,192 and 256 bits.

In my example above, when I use this below line, encoding util the extra bytes got added to it
System.debug('Blob:-'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cryptoKey));
System.debug('Blob:-'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cryptoKey).length());

So, while decoding it instead of blob.valueOf we should use EncodingUtil.base64Decode(cryptoKey);

This will give the correct number of bytes.

The below updated code snippet will work perfectly fine:

```
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
System.debug('KeyBlobSize:-'+cryptoKey.size());
System.debug('Blob:-'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cryptoKey).length());

Blob newcryptoKey128 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('xGhMrqIixKvQ4S1bqv8CYw==');
Blob newcryptoKey192 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('kBsCore1SUxZ8sTxSU5FCGqUGLhJ8IGq');
Blob newcryptoKey256 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('Wc0gT/1xfFAjlRwip7l7MmEdjw7DzMXamEHLjyCOQQ0=');


system.debug('Size1:-'+newcryptoKey128.size());
system.debug('Size2:-'+newcryptoKey192.size());
system.debug('Size3:-'+newcryptoKey256.size());


Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Test data to encrypted');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', newcryptoKey256, data);
String encodedString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
system.debug('encodedString :-'+encodedString);
```